# UML Diagrams with C

Tags: c, uml

If I am using UML diagrams to depict a C program, can I have composition and aggregation or is that reserved just for Object Oriented Languages?

For example if I have a struct or a Buffer in my source that is only used for that particular segment of the code I assume is aggregation, because the lifecycle of that particular piece of code is dependent of the user using that file right?

Should I be using Association and Direct Association?

Comment: UML class diagrams are a better fit for languages that actually have classes (by some name), and C does not.  Nevertheless, you can represent C struct types via UML classes if you wish.  If you do that, then the aggregation and composition concepts do map to C -- I would use composition when one struct contains an instance or array of another as a member, and aggregation when the first struct contains a *pointer* or array of pointers to the other.

Comment: Why C does not directly support it, you very well can write OO programs in C. Then UML **might** make sense. (It is still controversial if it is anyway)

Comment: I remember a time I tried to make sense of UML diagrams for embedded C. Reached the conclusion that I better leave this idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use UML to describe programs in any language.
2. When an object (structure, w/e ) has it's lifecycle tight coupled with another object is Composition , not Aggregation
3. What you described is neither Composition nor Aggregation. The lifecycle of a particular structure/buffer that's only valid through a certain code segment can be better represented through a Sequence diagram (get buffer , release buffer calls should be shown in the diagram)
4. You will have allot of Composition and Aggregation in C. Think about POD structs. Some of them reference other POD structs inside them. If the reference comes with memory ownership it's Composition (eg :pointer which needs to be released). If the reference doesn't come with memory ownership it's Aggregation (eg : pointer which you don't have to release when releasing the structure).

Comment: What I do is to stereotype C-containers somehow (I often use <<utility>> but any name is ok as long as you describe the meaning). Those stereotyped classes are marked this way to be not real classes but some C-file with just operations.